# looking for an idea for "fondue alternative" dish, that can be served in a buffet

Tags: cheese, wine, fondue

I'm looking for an idea for a dish with fondue taste (mainly the combination of cheese and wine \ beer), but which can be served in a buffet (without constant heating, and something that can be eaten standing up)

Comment: Thanks, Ophir, but since this is primarily opinion based, it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Additionally, recipe requests are off topic. Everyone has their own favorites.

Comment: "which can be served in a buffet" is rather ambiguous ... are you just looking for something which doesn't need to be dipped individually, or do you have issues with it cooling off after people take it, or is there some other issue?

Comment: It can't be kept warm like fondue, and dipping is less convenient.

Comment: Requests for recipe recommendations are off-topic and this question will be closed.. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Any variation of the swiss holy trinity (lardon, cheese and potatoes) is good, but for maximum wow factor, see if you can rent a raclette oven or two and have someone stand by it and slide the molten cheese on people's plates :
[image]

Downside is you need a raclette officer on duty (can be done by anyone, its not hard)

Comment: "It can't be kept warm like fondue" was the reason I only mentioned this in passing. I assume "buffet style" is self service too. Otherwise, it's a great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Have a google for Raclette or Tartiflette (or anything from the Savoyard region of France).

Most mountainous dishes involve the involve the cheese "Reblochon" over some form of boiled potatoes. Although once considered the poor mans dish in the mountains, they are now vastly populor and there are many variations for the reciepe online.

My reciepe is:

1. Rub garlic over a raclette dish (or any oven proof dish if you don't have the specific one)
2. Finely slice potatoes and line the dish
3. For each layer, add fried lardons and fried onions and garlic
4. Add double cream to the dish
5. Cut a whole Reblochon cut in half around the waist, place with the skin facing outwards
6. Bake for around an hour at 180

You'll be able to fine a more accurate recipe online but it's a great dish for sharing and is useually serves with pickles and deli meat, but can just be a side dish.

If you wanted that beer or wine taste added, I'd suggest adding it to the onions and reducing a bit before adding to the dish.

For a veggy version, just leave out the bacon!